Does anyone have a name for a model that is by nature in a feedback loop?
I'm hoping someone could help me find some literature on a situation I'm dealing with, even if it's just by providing a name for what the system is called. Also, it is entirely possible I'm imagining an issue here so if that's the case, please feel free to let me know.
I'm working on a model of rents for my employer. I've been calling the model incestuous as what happens is the model creates predictions for rents, those predictions are sent to the field where managers attempt to get said rents for a given unit. When a unit is filled the rent they captured goes back into the database where it is given primacy as the outcome variable for much of our modeling efforts. I'm not sure how closely they adhere to the predictions but my understanding is it's definitely something they take seriously.
If that's not sticky enough, in the model I'm updating about 80% of the variables use dynamic data that's updated daily... except for for the single family residence values (gleaned from an outside source). That was put in in 2022 and has remained 2022 data. The reason being, extracting it like trying to take out a bad tooth in the 1860s. If we try to replace it with more recent data it hammers goodness of fit metrics. Enough so that my boss questions why we would update it if we're only getting accuracy that's as good as before. So I decided just to try every combination (technically there are two variables rooted in this data, one is an average of the year's values the other is growth 21-22) of every year 2020 forward. Seasonally adjusted, non seasonally adjusted, including condos, strictly SFR, just throw everything at the wall and surely something will be better. That stupid 2022 variable and it's cousin 21-22 growth were at the top as measured by R-Squared and AIC.
So now my colleagues and I had an idea. That is, this variable has informed every price prediction for the past two years. Since it was introduced it has been creating our rent variable. The reason why it's so good at predicting is that it is a proxy for the outcome variable. So I split the data up by moveins in 22, 23, 24 (rent doesn't move much for in place tenants in our communities) and checked the correlation between the home values 22 variable and rent in each of those subsets. If it's a proxy for quality of neighborhoods, wealth, etc then it should be strongest in 22 and then decrease from there. Of course... it did the exact opposite.
So at this point I'm convinced this variable is, mildly put, quite wonky and just think we have to rip the bandaid off even if the model is technically worse off and move toward the variable being dynamically updated. Based on how much that correlation was increasing, eventually this variable will become so powerful it's going to join Skynet and take out humanity, you know? But the only way to ensure buy in from my boss is to make myself a mini-expert on what's going on so I can make the strongest case possible. And unfortunately I don't even know what to call what's going on. So I can't do my homework here. We've alternately been calling it self-referential, recursive, feedback loop, etc. but none of those are yielding information. If any of the wise minds here have any information or thoughts on this issue it would be greatly appreciated!
